# How to deploy linux container on windows server?

Tags: windows, docker, ansible, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

What is the best way to run Linux docker container on Windows Server? Can anyone suggest me which way i can deploy my applications to windows servers?

below the configurations are done:

) jenkins - master- 2 linux slave and 1 windows slave
) am able to create app image and push to registry
) now i need to deploy my app to windows servers. please advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just install Docker on windows server https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/. By default Docker at windows starts linux images. So you will be able to use docker command at windows to start your Linux image.

Comment: i am able to create and run the images on windows... need to automate through jenkins

Comment: You want jenkins to start docker container on slave machine? Or just use slave for build needs?

Comment: Your slave Jenkins can use docker commands to deploy containers.

Comment: how to connect to deployment servers ? can we use ansible for this

Comment: Oh I see. Deployment servers are outside jenkins. Are deployment servers Linux?

Comment: no.. those are windows servers.....

Comment: I have not used that kind of configuration with it, but with linux, you can use docker-machine to configure remote docker access. https://docs.docker.com/machine/overview/

Comment: But you should really consider changing deployment machines OS to Linux.

Comment: thanks a lot.... we are using linux for deployment now